Plot coastline over Xarray data for individual subplot
I'd like to overlay a coastline from cartopy onto one of my subplots but not the other, all of the solutions I've found so far lay the coastline over every subplot.
Here is what I'm currently generating -

Using the below code.
  fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5))
  da.max(dim=["latitude", "longitude"]).plot(ax=axes[0])
  da.max(dim=["year"]).plot.pcolormesh(x="longitude",y="latitude", ax=axes[1])

When I tried to set individual axis with fig.add_gridspec there were issues with outdated engine compatibility presumably between xarray plotting and Matplotlib?
It's unclear how I could add a projection to an axis not the figure.
The country I want to overlay is Australia btw.

Can you do
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
da.max(dim=["latitude", "longitude"]).plot(ax=ax1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection=my_chosen_projection)
da.max(dim=["year"]).plot.pcolormesh(x="longitude",y="latitude", ax=ax2)
ax2.coastlines()

?

False alarm, I thought it worked but it just produced the same as what I already have. I need to add the coastline over somehow

I added a line for coastlines.

For some reason the code runs but no coastline is drawn.

I think this should work but I suspect Xarray is getting in the way. So I'm tempted to select this as the answer because in general I think this solves the problem

Changing this from ax=fig.add_subplot to ax= plt.subplot made it work.
